# Scikit learn preprocessing cannot understand the output using min_frequency argument in OneHotencoder class

Tags: scikit-learn

Consider the below array `t`. When using `min_frequency` kwarg in the `OneHotEncoder` class, I cannot understand why the category `snake` is still present when transforming a new array. There are 2/40 events of this label. Should the shape of `e` be (4,3) instead?

`sklearn.__version__ == '1.1.1'`

```py
t = np.array([['dog'] * 8 + ['cat'] * 20 + ['rabbit'] * 10 +
               ['snake'] * 2], dtype=object).T
enc = OneHotEncoder(min_frequency= 4/40, 
                    sparse=False).fit(t)

print(enc.infrequent_categories_)
# [array(['snake'], dtype=object)]

e = enc.transform(np.array([['dog'], ['cat'], ['dog'], ['snake']]))
array([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]]) # snake is present?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `enc.get_feature_names_out()`:

```py
array(['x0_cat', 'x0_dog', 'x0_rabbit', 'x0_infrequent_sklearn'],
      dtype=object)
```

"snake" isn't considered its own category anymore, but lumped into the infrequent category.  If you added some other rare categories, they'd be assigned to the same, and if you additionally set `handle_unknown="infrequent_if_exist"`, you would also encode unseen categories to the same.

Comment: thank you! This makes way more sense. Only when a second infrequent (or unknown If flag is set) is present we will see a shape change in the number of features output after encoding.